# Facebook graph API /me/permissions?access_token=XYZ returns 500 response with error - unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Tags: java, facebook-graph-api, ssl

My application validates user permissions based on the the access token and I am hitting - https://graph.facebook.com/me/permissions?access_token=XYZ URL with a valid token.

Things were working fine, however recently it has started breaking. HTTP GET on the mentioned URL returns 500 response with an error -

> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

There are no changes on the code front.

Moreover,

1. The mentioned URL with a valid token works fine when I hit it in the browser. But in code it does not work.
2. Also when I run the application on my laptop this all works fine. But it fails with the mentioned error on the production.

Not sure what's going on .. Can anyone please help me in this ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please note, that this is not a free code-writing service, but we are eager to help fellow programmers (and aspirants) writing their own code. Please read the help topics on [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Afterwards, please update your question with the code you have written thus far in order to complete the task(s) you wish to achieve.

Comment: did you already try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21076179/pkix-path-building-failed-and-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requ) ?